# Why Rider does not highlight some warnings in C#?

Tags: c#, resharper, roslyn, rider, roslyn-code-analysis

I have the following example of CS0279 rule violation. In VS the waning is highlighted, but in Rider it is not. Some of CS* rules in Rider are highlighted and some are not.

```
public class myTest : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return 0;
    }

    internal IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return 0;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (int i in new myTest()) {}  // CS0279
    }
}
```

[Rider warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Ku9.png)

[VS warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf8QQ.png)

I have tried to find something about Resharper in Rider settings but there was nothing.

Comment: Have you tried **increasing the memory allotment** from the menu `help` > `change memory settings` and also be sure to **exclude the Rider application folder** from any antivirus software scanning?

Comment: @HunterYavitz I just increased the memory from 2048 to 4096 and nothing changed. Also, some of IDE* rules are not highlighted in Rider and are highlighted in VS. I think it is about the analysers that are used in VS in Rider

Comment: The two IDEs use different designs so naturally work differently. If you want Rider to emulate perfectly, you might report bugs like this to JetBrains.

Answer (score 2):

`CS0279` is what Microsoft calls a [*level 2 compiler warning*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0279). Warnings like this are only displayed when actually compiling the code:
[image]

AFAIK it's not possible to display them without compiling, but as I'm curious too, I've contacted JetBrains and will keep you posted.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And moreover, Rider does not highlight some IDEXXX rules. For example, IDE0001. But VS does it perfectly